# How to set colorspace of PDF generated with UIKit?

Tags: ios, pdf, uikit, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate print-ready PDFs using UIKit (UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData, etc.). One of the requirements from the printer is that the PDF be in a greyscale colorspace. I'm generating a PDF directly from a UIView that contains a UIImageView and a few UILabels.

I checked and the PDFs generated by default are in an RGB colorspace. This might be a holdover from the UIImageView, who's image is in RGB colorspace (not sure how to change that either).

Any ideas?